# clicking on a link in an email using qtp

Tags: qtp, hp-uft

I'm trying to open an autogenerated url sent in an email as part of an activation process.
I am unable to get qtp to open that link. Infact,I don't know how to do it.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your record settings you can set the options to record windows applications (location Record > Record and Run Settings > Windows Applications). Here is an example of a script that clicks a login link from an email from stackoverflow -- using UFT 12:

```
'To open Outlook
SystemUtil.Run "OUTLOOK.EXE"
Window("Microsoft Outlook").Activate

'Double click the top message in the inbox
Window("Outlook Inbox Column").WinObject("Table View").DblClick 118,72

'Find the location of the link within the Message
Window("Message (HTML)").WinObject("Message").Click 212,324

'Verify the link brought me to the Stack Overflow Login page
Browser("Add a login - Stack Overflow").WinObject("AddressDisplay Control").Check CheckPoint("AddressDisplay Control")
```

Comment: Many thanks @EDuncan. This has worked. My script now clicks on the activation email.

Answer (score 1):

```
Function OpenMailAndVerify(ByVal strSubject,Byval Activity)
Set objApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objNameSpace = objApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set objSyncs = objNameSpace.SyncObjects
Set objSync = objSyncs.Item("All Accounts")
objSync.Start
Set myFolder = objNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(6)
Set ObjMails = myFolder.Items
Set objFilter = ObjMails
Flag_EmailFound = False

For Each objItem In objFilter
    If InStr(objItem.Subject, strSubject) = 1 Then
        dtMyDate = objItem.SentOn
        strSubject = objItem.Subject
        strBody = objItem.Body
        StartPos = InStr(strBody, "HYPERLINK")
        EndPos = InStr(strBody, "Direct Link to Activity")
        EndPos = EndPos - 1
        StartPos = StartPos + Len("HYPERLINK") + 2
        ActualLink = Mid(strBody, StartPos, EndPos - StartPos)

        Flag_EmailFound = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next


If (Flag_EmailFound) Then
systemutil.Run ActualLink,,,,3
wait 5
  If Browser("name:="&Activity&".*").Page("title:="&Activity&".*").Exist(10) Then
     Browser("name:="&Activity&".*").Page("title:="&Activity&".*").Highlight

  End If
End if
```

End Function

Answer (score 0):

Use RegExp to identify the link by name and using descriptive programming you can click on the link

Example:

1. http://www.cnn.com/2014/06/15/us/nyt-chelsea-manning/index.html?hpt=us_c2
2. http://www.cnn.com/2014/06/16/us/bowe-bergdahl-case/index.html?hpt=us_c2

This will be code

```
    urlString = "http://www.cnn.com/.*"
    Browser("name:=test - .* - Gmail").Page("title:=test - .* - Gmail").Link("name:=" &urlString).Click
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Rohit.I should've been clear. The email is an outlook email not a browser based email.I'm using the following code to read the 1st email in a shared mailbox which contains a link I need to click on.                                               Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objNameSpace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")

Set objFolder= objNameSpace.Folders(2)

objFolder.display()
Set InboxFolder =objFolder.Folders("Inbox")
msgbox "Opened " &objFolder
 
For Each x In InboxFolder.Items
x.Display
msgbox x.Body
Exit For
Next